# winrt textblock run binding designtime

Tags: xaml, binding, windows-runtime

my datacontext in designtime

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewmodel:MainViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
....
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Driver}">
```

work fine. Only in:

```
<TextBlock/>
    <Run Text="{Binding Path=Jahr}" />
</TextBlock>
```

dont work in designtime, why?

Answer (score 4):

**NOTE:** It **IS** possible to bind to a `<Run />` but it won't render at Design-Time, only Run-time.

This works a treat for binding.

```
    <TextBlock>
        <Run Text="{Binding Results.Count}" />
        <Run Text=" results for '" />
        <Run Text="{Binding SearchTerm}" />
        <Run Text="'"/>
    </TextBlock>
```

You can't set the `TextBlock` Text *AND* a `Run` Binding though. It's either one or the other, this works fine, but doesn't render at design time as you say.

Comment: Works only in run-time, but not in design time, unfortunately.

Comment: @Sevenate That's right, I mentioned that in my answer.

Comment: Right, but it seems that the question was about why it is not working in exactly **design-time** and not about whether it works at all (i.e. in run-time), and your answer sounds in general a bit more positive than it is in reality and may gives to someone false hopes (if they will not read it till the very end).

Comment: @Sevenate It's a fair point, at the time the accepted answer stated that it was impossible to Bind to a Run which was wrong, this answer was corrective, you can bind to them, but it won't render at design-time. Regardless, I'll update the answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Runs do support binding in Windows Runtime but it seems that those Run Controls do not support design time data... :-(

Comment: And the reason for this is may be because [Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.documents.run.aspx) is [Inline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.documents.inline.aspx) descendant, rather then [FrameworkElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.aspx) that have our beloved [DataContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) property.